# Root term in Pathauto only works for child terms?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases

My taxonomy structure looks like this:

```
Film
- Short film
- Special film
```

Using Pathauto, I would like the url to always include the root term.

So for nodes tagged with 'film' the path is: *film/node-title*. For nodes tagged with 'short film' the path is also: *film/node-title*

I thought the 'root term' token would do the trick, setting pathauto pattern to: `[node:field-category:root:name]/[node:title]`

But it only works for children. If a film is tagged 'film', the token isn't used for some reason. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the meaning of 'root'?

Comment: Why do you don't set it fix as a pattern? Pattern = film/[node:title]

Comment: Good point. It's because my vocabulary has other terms with children, such as Concert->Acoustic, Concert->Fundraising etc.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and wrote the patch for token module
Here is patch https://drupal.org/node/2050421#comment-7806099